# Linux HTTP server Network Settings

Tags: networking, dhcp

I'm having a hard time to find a network configuration for a system that I'm developing. I start by stating that I'm not a network expert, so i'm sorry for something that is not so well explained.

I'm developing a system that is composed by 3 linux devices. One of them is an HTTP Server. Until now all 3 linux devices were configured to have Fixed IPs (192.168.1.20/24 - 192.168.1.21/24 - 192.168.1.22/24). This way any computer (User) in the network could access the HTTP server.

Now I'm trying to integrate my system into a third party device. And here comes the problem.

- This device needs access to the HTTP Server.
- This device has a fixed IP 245.* .* .* .
- This device has a DHCP Server
- This device is optional. Sometimes is present in the network, sometimes is not.
- My HTTP server needs to obtain an IPv4 address via DHCP (from this third party device)
- The HTTP server needs to advertise the HTTP service to the third party device via multicast DNS.

I can make this system work by configuring the HTTP server to get a dynamic IP from the DHCP server (245.* .* .*).But this way:

- the users on the network lose access to the HTTP Server.
- when I connect my system to a router and to the third party device it's problematic (because now my system is connected to 2 DHCP servers - router and third party device).
- when neither the router nor the third party device is connected there is no DHCP server in the network, and I lose access to the HTTP Server.

Possible solutions that I tried but was not able to make it work:

- Multiple IPs in the HTTP server (one Fixed and one dynamic). Problem when there are 2 DHCP servers.
- Access via host name (users do not have to know the system IP to access to it) -> this way I can have just the dynamic IP. I think this solution might bring problem in other networks.

Does someone has any ideia what could be the network settings for the HTTP server and the other 2 linux devices?

I will leave here also a diagram of the network (I dont know if it is well done or not but it might help)

Things in grey are not always present in the network.

[image]

If something is not well explained please just ask. I'm new here :)

Comment: lookup notion of a reverse proxy ... nginx or haproxy are both good ... this allows external traffic say from your User1 , User2 to reach your http server using the domain name of http server such that only the reverse proxy needs to care about actual IP values for hidden services like your http server

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment, I dont understand how this would solve the problem. Can you be more detailed? Many Thanks